# Слово "вывеска" в обозначении куска мяса

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, история

Порой говорят: "Мясная вывеска", "Баранья вывеска", "У моего друга есть пара килограмм свежей вывески" - под "вывеской" имеется в виду мясо. Но я не могу найти этого значения слова ни в одном словаре. Почему про мясо говорят "вывеска"?

И откуда в целом пошло слово "вывеска"? Раньше мясо вывешивали напоказ из магазина для привлечения клиентов и так и пошло (это моя версия)? Я нигде не могу отыскать историю этого слова.

Comment: Что я говорил?) "Пару килограмм". А кто-то ещё не верил.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой , как правильно? х)

Comment: Правильнее "есть пара килограмм", Helena, именительный падеж. :)

Comment: _Helena: Порой говорят:"Мясная вы**в**еска"..._ === Может, человек просто букву "р" не выговаривает?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, спасибо! Изменила. А по самому вопросу можете что-то сказать?

Comment: @slava1947, точно уверена, что "вывеска", а не "вырезка" - читала и слышала именно "вывеска".

Comment: _Helena: ... **читала** и слышала именно "вывеска"._ === Ссылками не поделитесь?

Comment: @slava1947, это в бумажных книгах было и тех книг уже не помню, но контекст слова запал ещё тогда. Сегодня "вывеску" в сериале услышала и вспомнила про это слово в таком значении, начала искать - серией могу поделиться.

Comment: К сожалению, не сталкивался с таким. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При заготовке, транспортировании и хранении мясо «подвешивают».

«…полутуши или четверти охлаждаются в подвешенном виде…»
«При хранении охлаждённого мяса к нему должен обеспечиваться свободный доступ воздуха, поэтому туши должны находиться в подвешенном состоянии, не касаясь друг друга и стен камеры».
https://ooopht.ru/hranenie-myasa.html

При вялении мясо «вывешивают».

«После этого, чтобы мясо обсохло, пересыпать отрубями и вывесить в теплом месте для сушки. Через месяц солонина может быть употребляема как провесная». https://eda.wikireading.ru/142388

Возможно, что выражением «мясная вывеска» называют цельный кусок (мяса), вывешиваемый для просушки в процессе вяления или для длительного хранения готового продукта.

Answer (score 1):

Бросили кусок мяса на весы, приклеили ярлычок. Получилась мясная вывеска.